# Fragment Back Navigation Blocked by ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack, android-mvvm

So I'm trying to implement mvvm architecture with navigation component, this code snipet works just fine.. the problem is that when I navigate from fragmentA to FragmentB there is no way to go back to FragmentA, its like the button is blocked (If I remove the ViewModel the navigation works fine so it has something to do with the ViewModel).

anyone have an idea of whats happening?

```
private fun initVewModel() {
    myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    myViewModel = ViewModelProviders
        .of(this, createFor(myViewModel))
        .get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

private fun setupObservers() {
    myViewModel.myData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    resource.data?.let {
                        val action =
                            FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB()
                        Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)
                    }
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    //TODO show an error
                    loading.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                Status.LOADING -> {
                    loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    })

}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val searchText = MutableLiveData<String>()

    //This method is called on a search button click
    fun setSearchText(text: String) {
        searchText.value = text
    }

    val myData = searchText.switchMap { text ->
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
            try {
                emit(Resource.success(data = dataOrigin.getData(text)))
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
                emit(Resource.error(data = null, message = exception.message ?: "Error Occurred!"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `myData` `Observer` will be immediately triggered with the latest data on back navigation and trigger the `SUCCESS` branch once again.

I recommend either using `SharedFlow`s or checking out a `SingleLiveEvent` pattern for `LiveData`, where you can only consume an event once.

**UPDATE:**

A possible solution for the consumable pattern:

```
class Consumable<T>(private val event: T) {
    private var isConsumed = false

    fun consume(): T? {
        if (isConsumed) return null
        isConsumed = true
        return event
    }

    fun peek() = event
}
```

Then in the **ViewModel**:

```
val event = MutableLiveData<Consumable<YourEventClass>>()
...
event.value = Consumable(XYEvent)
```

And you'd observe it like this:

```
viewModel.event.observe{ event ->
    event.consume()?.let{
         // Do your navigation here
    }

}
```

Additionally you could write an extension function `.consume()`, for consumable livedatas, which unwraps the value

Comment: I'm reading the documentation about SingleLiveEvent but I don't quite understand how to adapt it to my view model, could you help me a bit more if its not much trouble?